# SAP WEB IDE - Ignoring all font files except .ttf when deploying to ABAP

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-web-ide

Why does SAP WEB IDE ignore all .eot, otf, svg and woff when deploying to ABAP.

For example, SAP WEB IDE does not allow - in font filename, so we amended one font, replacing the -

AvenirLTStd-Heavy.ttf
AvenirLTStd-Heavy.eot
AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf
AvenirLTStd-Heavy.svg
AvenirLTStd-Heavy.woff

With and _

AvenirLTStd_Heavy.ttf
AvenirLTStd_Heavy.eot
AvenirLTStd_Heavy.otf
AvenirLTStd_Heavy.svg
AvenirLTStd_Heavy.woff

This deploys to ABAP without error, but ONLY the .ttf version?

Why?

Comment: what project type?

Comment: Web Project + SAP Fiori project types are ticked.

Comment: where did you place your fonts? in webapp/resource subfolder? how did you check there were not deployed? doesn't loaded in your app? how do you load it?

Comment: did you try to check [Web-IDE console](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/console_887184.png)? what does it show?

Comment: i **think** there's a white list in the neo-app.json for file types but my searches have come up blank so far

Comment: Hi @Suncatcher.  Fonts located in /WebContent/fonts folder. Console says it deployed the font no problem. I checked in ABAP (SE80) the fonts (bar the .ttfs) aren't there in the MIME objects.

Comment: Hi @Jorg . I googled the whitelist too with no joy.